# How to see the Account and Auth controllers in the Asp.net core MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to see the Account controller in Asp.net core MVC application .Only Home controller is visible in the Controllers folder.

[image]

Comment: You can add them by right clicking the controllers folder.

Comment: Account and Auth Controller Only Given in MVC. Dotnet core cannot give you Account and Auth Controller.You need to add it by your self.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Rejeti, Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 2):

In .net core 2.1 and later the Identity is provided as Razor pages (as a class library).

So if you want to see the code-behind you need to scaffold the identity by **right-clicking project** -> **New Scaffolded Item**. And from the popup-ed window select **Identity** -> **ADD**.

For more information check out [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using  **VS2017** then you Can add that manually like Bellow or see [How to Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

```
 1. Select File > New > Project.               
 2. Select ASP.NET Core Web Application. Name the project WebApp1 to
    have the same namespace as the project download. Click OK.              
 3. Select an ASP.NET Core Web Application for ASP.NET Core 2.1, then
    select Change Authentication.                
 4. Select Individual User Accounts and click OK.
```

[image]